# Showing set is closed

Tags: general-topology

Consider the set {$\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...,0$}. Show that this set is closed.

How would one approach such a question without pursuing an epsilon-delta kind of proof?

Comment: Call your set $S$. I would try to show that the compliment $\mathbb R - S$ is open.

Comment: What is our overall space, the real line with the usual topology?

Answer (score 0):

I assume we're thinking of this as a subset of the real line with the usual topology.

One way would be to show that its complement is the infinite union of intervals $$\bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}\right),$$ together with the intervals $(1/2, \infty)$ and $(-\infty, 0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Note thAT a set $S$ is closed if its complement is open in certain Euclidean Space and I think you are pertaining to $R$.

Try to find the complement of your given set and notice that it is an arbitrary union of open intervals. An arbitrary union of open set/interval(since we are working in $R$) is again open in $R$.

That is why your given set is closed in $R$, take note in $R$.

Lastly, do not forget to state on what space we are working since an open set in $R$ may not be open in other Euclidean space.